# Custom Attribute on return value

Tags: c#, attributes, return

I'm currently playing around with the Attribute class.
I'm trying to use an attribute on a return type of my class but unfortunately my attribute isn't applied. Am i missing something?

```
public class Model
{
    [return: Mandatory]
    public int Integer
    {
        [return: Mandatory]
        get { return 2; }
    }

    [Mandatory]
    public TimeSpan Time => TimeSpan.FromHours(2);

    [return: Mandatory]
    public Model2 GetModel2 => new Model2();

    [return: Mandatory]
    public Model2 Test()
    {
        return new Model2();
    }
}
```

If i'm inspecting for instance Model.Test().GetType() i'm seeing no custom attributes ... What could be the part i'm apparently missing? :(
(Model. is an abbreviation for (new Model()) ^^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `new Model().Test()` will return an object of `Model2`, on which you run `GetType()`. And `Model2` has no `[MandatoryAttribute]` on it, right? So the type information on `Model2` doesn't return any information about this.

I looked it up on MSDN and they're very vague about what is it for. But on the MSDN Forum I found this [Attributes on return values](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/afff21d4-28f9-44ea-93ca-542c04aad72d/attributes-on-return-values?forum=netfxbcl), and from one of the answers we get:

> In this case, the "return" attribute is describing something about everything that the property returns.  It's not describing any single return, but rather a characteristic of all of them.
>
> -Ryan / Kardax

So I believe that the `[return: Attribute]` is just an information about the method and what it may return, rather than an attribute assignable to the returned object.

An example from MSDN

```
[Guid("12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789abc"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface ISampleInterface
{
    [DispId(17)]  // set the DISPID of the method
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]  // set the marshaling on the return type 
    object DoWork();
}
```

So here the runtime uses this `MarshallAsAttribute` to properly operate on the return value, from an unmanaged environment.